# WSDL-First approach, not same WSDL deployed

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

Here is my approach (don't hesitate to tell me if I am doing something wrong) :

-Write XSD files defining my objects

-Use WSCF.blue to generate WSDL accordingly to the XSDs

-Use WSCF.blue to generate Web Service Code

-Implementing a stub and exposing the SVC

So far, I am not facing any problem. I can access to the .svc through my browser. But the thing is the deployed WSDL is not the same as the designed one.

When I tried to test the service with SOAP UI and the designed WSDL as source, it failed because the WSDL are differents. When I tried with the deployed one, it works fine.

Same result when I tried to generate a client (console application) with the designed WSDL (with SvcUtil.exe) : it fails the same way (ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher exception). it works I add a service reference.

I won't develop the client but the people they will will work on a WSDL I had to give them first. Is there a way to work with the designed WSDL or I had to give them the deployed one ?

Thanks in advance.

Excuse me for my english, I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can expose your own wsdl like this (using the example data from the wscf.blue walkthrough), with externalMetadataLocation being the important part:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="../ContractMetaData/RestaurantService.wsdl"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    ...
    <services>
      <service name="RestaurantService.RestaurantService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
        ...
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But I haven't had any luck making this work in conjunction with "add service reference". VS keeps generating code that isn't compatible with the webservice generated by wscf.blue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Unfortunatelly, I have already send the deployed WSDL to the other team. But I will keep it in mind for the next time ^^. (I vote has accepted answer but I didn't have time to check it)